# Intellij IDEA CE 2018.2.5 cannot run on macOS Mojave

Tags: intellij-idea, macos-mojave

I uninstall very slow and memory eating version of Intellij IDEA CE 2018.2.5. This happened because I upgrade my Mac Pro 2012 to Mojave (512 ssd and 16gb). I uninstalled it using cleanmymacx. I restart the Mac and download the Intellij IDEA CE 2018.2.5 and installed it. But now I cannot run the Intellij IDEA CE 2018.2.5. Simply it doesn't run. Any idea?

Comment: So [have you tried running it from terminal](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201468#focus=streamItem-27-3128248-0-0)? What output you see?

Comment: I delete everything including the log cache etc... reinstall it and it work. Luckly this morrinng also I get new macos mojave update 10.14.1. ıt seems no running or memeory leak isue now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing the latest version using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). I had to use `brew cask reinstall intellij-idea-ce` to upgrade from previous version.